# Cassandra vnodes token values

Tags: cassandra, replication

Each physical node in Cassandra is assigned 256 number of tokens/vnodes.
Do tokens in each vnode in Cassandra correspond to a particular keyspace only 
Example: say we have a vnode with token number 100 
The token range for this vnode is (1-100]
So this vnode can contain 100 different rows each with unique token numbers ranging between 1-100

Is it that all these 100 rows  which  constitute this  vnode...belong to the same keyspace.

Answer (score 3):

No, the rows are not part of the same keyspace. The default partitioner in Cassandra is Murmur3Partitioner which is using hashing to generate token values. In order to belong to the same vnode, it would mean that you would be able to restrict somehow the token generation. Then it wouldn't make sense to randomly distribute data across the cluster.